# How to store more than one option in a variable - Java

Tags: java

In Java, how would I create a property/field/variable that can at any one time store a couple of options/values, similar to lower level environments where you can set bits in variables, each meaning different things. I know that one can do this in Java by using static finals or something and then just ORing them all together, but isn't there a more elegant solution? E.g in C# where you can have the [Flags] attribute to an Enum and then OR the states/values together into an instance of that Enum.

Any ideas?

Renault

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can use an enum and then have an [`EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) for that enum. It's hard to know exactly what to recommend without more information. `EnumSet` is a good choice when you're naturally dealing with just "options" - but if you have multiple *values* (e.g. height and width; a fixed number of values which just naturally come together) then I'd just create a new type to encapsulate them.

If you could give concrete examples of what you're looking for, we may be able to help more.

Answer (score 1):

The old-fashioned way (that you can still find in many libraries) would be to encode a bit mask using either an int value or a [BitSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html), but since JDK 1.5, an EnumSet is the preferred way to do it, [as Jon Skeet says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767200/how-to-store-more-than-one-option-in-a-variable-java/3767225#3767225).

Answer (score 0):

You mean like a C++ union? This is not allowed in Java because you lose type safety; this would allow you to get a reference to an `Integer` typed as a `String`, for example.